# JRadioButtons selection doesn't update

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcombobox, jradiobutton

When I run the program I'm able to select one smiley to be active, and I can change this from the JRadio button choices to different selections and it'd work cause I'm testing it with changing colors.

My issue is that I'm only able to change active panels by descending order. I can't go back to a previous one. When  I run the program and select smiley_a, I'm able to change its colors, but when I select smiley_b, smiley_a continues the be the one that's changing. Once I get to A, I can't go back to or C or D, and if I start with B, I can't go back to C or D, only to A, and so forth. I'm able to click, but it doesn't update which frame is active.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String action = e.getActionCommand();
    if (action.equals("Change Colors")) {
        update();
        selector();
    }
    if (action.equals("Face +")) {
        System.out.println("work");
        //frameAsmiley.setSize(20);
        //System.out.println("work");
        //frameAsmiley.repaint();
    }
    if (action.equals("Face -")) {
        frameAsmiley.setSize(20);
        frameAsmiley.repaint();
    }
}
@Override

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == a) {
        smiley_a = true;
        update();
    }if (source == b) {
        smiley_b = true;
        update();
    }if (source== c) {
        smiley_c = true;
        update();
    }if (source == d) {
        smiley_d = true;
        update();
    }

    if (source == glasses_on) {
        cube_a.repaint();
    }if (source == glasses_off) {
        cube_a.repaint();
    }if (source== c) {
        smiley_c = true;
        update();
    }if (source == d) {
        smiley_d = true;
        update();
    }

    if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
        if (emotions.getSelectedItem().equals("Smile!")) {
        }
        if (emotions.getSelectedItem().equals("Angry!")) {
        }if (emotions.getSelectedItem().equals("Sad!")) {
        }if (emotions.getSelectedItem().equals("Shock!")) {
        }if (emotions.getSelectedItem().equals("Wink!")) {
        }
    }
}

class OutputScreen extends JPanel {
    OutputScreen() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
    }
}
```

This is my main code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder;

public class SmileyTwo extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener {
    private final int framewidth = 1200, frameheight = 1000;
    private final int cubes_width = framewidth / 4 - 10, cubes_height = frameheight / 4 - 10;
    JPanel mainpanel, cube_1, cube_2, cube_3, cube_4, control_panel_u, control_panel_d, selectsmiley = new JPanel();
    JButton color;
    JComboBox emotions;
    Smiley frameAsmiley, frameBsmiley, frameCsmiley, frameDsmiley, currentpanel;
    ButtonGroup eyesopenorclose, glasses_toggle, glasses_state, smileyselector;
    JRadioButton eyes_open, eyes_closed, glasses_on, glasses_off, glasses_dark, glasses_clear, a, b, c, d;
    JRadioButton left_eye_closed, right_eye_closed = new JRadioButton();
    JLabel emotes, smiley, eyestate, glass_state;
    Container screen;
    boolean smiley_a = false, smiley_b = false, smiley_c = false, smiley_d = false;
    int smiley_int_width = 200, smiley_int_height = 200, smiley_face_x_int = 200, smiley_face_y_int = 100;
    int smiley_eyes_w = smiley_int_width / 4, smiley_eyes_h = smiley_int_width / 4;
    int smileyCtrPoint_x = smiley_face_x_int + smiley_int_width / 2, smileyCtrPoint_y = smiley_face_y_int + smiley_int_height / 2;
    int left_eye_x = smileyCtrPoint_x - 80, left_eye_y = smileyCtrPoint_y - 50;
    int right_eye_x = smileyCtrPoint_x + 80, right_eye_y = smileyCtrPoint_y - 50;
    public OutputScreen cube_a, cube_b, cube_c, cube_d;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int face = 100;
        SmileyTwo frame = new SmileyTwo();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(frame.framewidth, frame.frameheight));
        frame.setTitle("SMILEY");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.createGui();
        frame.repaint();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void controlBox() {
        JPanel glasses = new JPanel();
        JPanel emojis = new JPanel();
        JPanel expressions = new JPanel();
        JPanel eyes_choices = new JPanel();
        JPanel eyepanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel glasspanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel selectsmiley = new JPanel();
        control_panel_u = new JPanel();
        control_panel_d = new JPanel();
        smileyselector = new ButtonGroup();
        eyes_open = new JRadioButton();
        eyes_closed = new JRadioButton();
        glasses_on = new JRadioButton();
        glasses_off = new JRadioButton();
        glasses_dark = new JRadioButton();
        glasses_clear = new JRadioButton();
        left_eye_closed = new JRadioButton();
        right_eye_closed = new JRadioButton();
        //
        JLabel smiley = new JLabel();
        smiley.setText("TOGGLE SMILEY BOX");
        a = new JRadioButton();
        b = new JRadioButton();
        c = new JRadioButton();
        d = new JRadioButton();
        a.addItemListener(this);
        b.addItemListener(this);
        c.addItemListener(this);
        d.addItemListener(this);
        JPanel smileyoptions = new JPanel();
        JButton color = new JButton("Change Colors");
        color.addActionListener(this);
        emotes = new JLabel();
        emotes.setText("SELECT EMOJI");
        emotes.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        emotions = new JComboBox();
        emotions.addItem("Smile!");
        emotions.addItem("Wink!");
        emotions.addItem("Shock!");
        emotions.addItem("Angry!");
        emotions.addItem("Sad!");
        emotions.setSize(30, 10);
        emotions.addItemListener(this);
        emojis.add(emotions);

        emojis.add(color);
        expressions.add(emotes);
        expressions.add(emojis);
        expressions.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        //
        eyestate = new JLabel("EYE OPTIONS");
        ButtonGroup eyesopenorclose = new ButtonGroup();
        eyes_choices.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        eyes_choices.add(eyes_open);
        eyes_choices.add(left_eye_closed);
        eyes_choices.add(eyes_closed);
        eyes_choices.add(right_eye_closed);
        eyepanel.add(eyestate);
        eyepanel.add(eyes_choices);
        eyes_open.setText("open both eyes");
        eyes_closed.setText("close both eyes");
        left_eye_closed.setText("close right eye");
        right_eye_closed.setText("close left eye");
        eyesopenorclose.add(eyes_open);
        eyesopenorclose.add(eyes_closed);
        eyesopenorclose.add(left_eye_closed);
        eyesopenorclose.add(right_eye_closed);
        eyepanel.add(eyestate);
        eyestate.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        eyepanel.add(eyes_choices);
        eyepanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        //
        glass_state = new JLabel("GLASSES OPTIONS");
        ButtonGroup glasses_toggle = new ButtonGroup();
        ButtonGroup glasses_state = new ButtonGroup();
        glasses_on.setText("glasses on");
        glasses_off.setText("glasses off");
        glasses_dark.setText("dark shades");
        glasses_clear.setText("clear glasses");
        glasses_on.addItemListener(this);
        glasses_off.addItemListener(this);
        glasses_dark.addItemListener(this);
        glasses_clear.addItemListener(this);
        glasses_toggle.add(glasses_off);
        glasses_toggle.add(glasses_on);
        glasses_state.add(glasses_dark);
        glasses_state.add(glasses_clear);
        GridLayout forglass = new GridLayout(2, 2);
        glasses.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        glasses.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        glasses.add(glasses_on);
        glasses.add(glasses_dark);
        glasses.add(glasses_off);
        glasses.add(glasses_clear);
        glasspanel.add(glass_state);
        glasspanel.add(glasses);
        glass_state.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        glasspanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        //
        smileyselector.add(a);
        smileyselector.add(b);
        smileyselector.add(c);
        smileyselector.add(d);
        a.setText("Smiley A");
        b.setText("Smiley B");
        c.setText("Smiley C");
        d.setText("Smiley D");
        smileyoptions.add(a);
        smileyoptions.add(b);
        smileyoptions.add(c);
        smileyoptions.add(d);
        selectsmiley.add(smiley);
        selectsmiley.add(smileyoptions);
        smiley.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        selectsmiley.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        //
        control_panel_u.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        control_panel_u.add(selectsmiley);
        control_panel_u.add(expressions);
        control_panel_u.add(glasspanel);
        control_panel_u.add(eyepanel);
        control_panel_u.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        glasses.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        eyes_choices.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        emojis.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    }

    public void createGui() {
        controlBox();
        selector();
        Smiley frameAsmiley = new Smiley(150, 100, 400, 400, "shock");
        Smiley frameBsmiley = new Smiley(150, 100, 400, 400, "frown");
        Smiley frameCsmiley = new Smiley(150, 100, 400, 400,"smile");
        Smiley frameDsmiley = new Smiley(150, 100, 400, 400, "wink");

        currentpanel = frameAsmiley;
        screen = getContentPane();
        mainpanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel cubepanels = new JPanel();
        cube_1 = new JPanel();
        cube_2 = new JPanel();
        cube_3 = new JPanel();
        cube_4 = new JPanel();
        cube_a = new OutputScreen();
        cube_b = new OutputScreen();
        cube_c = new OutputScreen();
        cube_d = new OutputScreen();
        cube_1.setSize(cubes_width, cubes_height);
        cube_2.setSize(cubes_width, cubes_height);
        cube_3.setSize(cubes_width, cubes_height);
        cube_4.setSize(cubes_width, cubes_height);
        cube_a.setSize(cubes_width - 5, cubes_height - 50);
        cube_b.setSize(cubes_width - 5, cubes_height);
        cube_c.setSize(cubes_width - 5, cubes_height);
        cube_d.setSize(cubes_width - 5, cubes_height);
        mainpanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        cube_1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        cube_2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        cube_3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        cube_4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        cubepanels.add(cube_1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        cubepanels.add(cube_2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        cubepanels.add(cube_3, BorderLayout.EAST);
        cubepanels.add(cube_4, BorderLayout.WEST);
        cubepanels.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        mainpanel.add(cubepanels, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainpanel.add(control_panel_u, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        cube_a.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frameAsmiley.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 500));
        frameBsmiley.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 500));
        frameCsmiley.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 500));
        frameDsmiley.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 500));
        //
        cube_a.add(frameAsmiley, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cube_1.add(cube_a, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cube_1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cube_1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frameAsmiley.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //
        cube_b.add(frameBsmiley, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cube_2.add(cube_b, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cube_2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cube_2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frameBsmiley.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //
        cube_c.add(frameCsmiley, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cube_3.add(cube_c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cube_3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cube_3, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frameCsmiley.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //
        cube_d.add(frameDsmiley, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cube_4.add(cube_d, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cube_4.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cube_4, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frameDsmiley.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //
        screen.add(mainpanel);
    }

    public void selector() {
        if (smiley_a == true) {
            smiley_b = false;
            smiley_c = false;
            smiley_d = false;
            cube_a.repaint();
        } else if (smiley_b == true) {
            smiley_a = false;
            smiley_c = false;
            smiley_d = false;
            cube_b.repaint();
        } else if (smiley_c == true) {
            smiley_a = false;
            smiley_b = false;
            smiley_d = false;
            cube_c.repaint();
        } else if (smiley_d == true) {
            smiley_a = false;
            smiley_b = false;
            smiley_c = false;
            cube_d.repaint();
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        if (smiley_a == true) {
            smiley_b = false;
            smiley_c = false;
            smiley_d = false;
        } else if (smiley_b == true) {
            smiley_a = false;
            smiley_c = false;
            smiley_d = false;
        } else if (smiley_c == true) {
            smiley_a = false;
            smiley_b = false;
            smiley_d = false;
        } else if (smiley_d == true) {
            smiley_a = false;
            smiley_b = false;
            smiley_c = false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String action = e.getActionCommand();
        if (action.equals("Change Colors")) {
            update();
            selector();
        }
        if (action.equals("Face +")) {
            System.out.println("work");
            frameAsmiley.setSize(20);
            //System.out.println("work");
            frameAsmiley.repaint();
        }
        if (action.equals("Face -")) {
            frameAsmiley.setSize(20);
            frameAsmiley.repaint();
        }
    }
    @Override

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == a) {
            smiley_a = true;
            update();
        }if (source == b) {
            smiley_b = true;
            update();
        }if (source== c) {
            smiley_c = true;
            update();
        }if (source == d) {
            smiley_d = true;
            update();
        }

        if (source == glasses_on) {
            cube_a.repaint();
        }if (source == glasses_off) {
            cube_a.repaint();
        }if (source== c) {
            smiley_c = true;
            update();
        }if (source == d) {
            smiley_d = true;
            update();
        }

        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
            if (emotions.getSelectedItem().equals("Smile!")) {
            }
            if (emotions.getSelectedItem().equals("Angry!")) {
            }if (emotions.getSelectedItem().equals("Sad!")) {
            }if (emotions.getSelectedItem().equals("Shock!")) {
            }if (emotions.getSelectedItem().equals("Wink!")) {
            }
        }
    }


    class OutputScreen extends JPanel {
        OutputScreen() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        }


    }
}
```

**this is the custom class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.Object.*;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Smiley extends JPanel {

        public Smiley(int x, int y, int width, int height, String mood) {
            this.x = x - 20;
            this.y = y - 70;
            this.width = width - 100;
            this.height = height - 100;
            this.mood = mood;
        }

        public Color randomColor() {
            int R = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            int G = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            int B = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            int A = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
            Color randomColor = new Color(A, R, G, B);
            return randomColor;
        }

        public int x, y, width, height;
        String mood;
        HashSet specs;
        public int geteyeheight() {
            int eyeHeight = height / 5;
            return eyeHeight;
        }
        public String currentlook() {
            String currentlook = mood;
            return currentlook;
        }
        public int geteyewidth() {
            int eyeWidth = width / 5;
            return eyeWidth;
        }

        public int getlefteyeX() {
            int centerPointX = (x + width) / 2;
            int leftEyeX = centerPointX - 40;
            return leftEyeX;
        }

        public int getlefteyeY() {
            int centerPointY = (y + height) / 2;
            int leftEyeY = centerPointY - 50;
            return leftEyeY;
        }

        public int getrighteyeX() {
            int centerPointX = (x + width) / 2;
            int rightEyeX = centerPointX + 110;
            return rightEyeX;
        }
        public int getrighteyeY() {
            int centerPointY = (y + height) / 2;
            int rightEyeY = centerPointY - 50;
            return rightEyeY;
        }

        public int getsmileY() {
            int centerPointY = (y + height) / 2;
            int smileYint = centerPointY + 20;
            return smileYint;
        }

        public int getsmileX() {
            int centerPointX = (x + width) / 2;
            int smileXint = centerPointX - 10;
            return smileXint;
        }

        public int getsmilewidth() {
            int smilewidth = width / 2;
            return smilewidth;
        }

        public int getsmileheight() {
            int smileheight = height / 3;
            return smileheight;
        }
    public void setSize(int size){
        height+=size;
        width+=size;
    }
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setColor(randomColor());
            g2d.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
            g2d.setColor(randomColor());
            if (currentlook().equals("smile")) {
                DrawSmile(g);
            }
            else if(currentlook().equals("frown")){
                DrawFrown(g);
            }else if(currentlook().equals("angry")){
                DrawAngry(g);
            }else if(currentlook().equals("wink")){
                DrawWink(g);
            }else if(currentlook().equals("shock")){
                DrawShock(g);
            }

            
        }

        //INDIVIDUAL FACIAL FEATURES
        public void rightEye(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.fillOval(getrighteyeX(), getrighteyeY(), geteyewidth(), geteyeheight());
        }
       
        public void leftEye(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.fillOval(getlefteyeX(), getlefteyeY(), geteyewidth(), geteyeheight());
        }

        public void leftEyeAngry(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawLine(getlefteyeX() + 20, getlefteyeY(), getlefteyeX() + 50, getrighteyeY() + 30);
            g2d.fillOval(getlefteyeX() + 15, getlefteyeY() + 25, 30, 30);
        }

        public void rightEyeAngry(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawLine(getrighteyeX() + 30, getrighteyeY(), getrighteyeX(), getrighteyeY() + 30);
            g2d.fillOval(getlefteyeX() + 155, getlefteyeY() + 25, 30, 30);
        }

        public void CloseLeftEye(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
            g2d.drawArc(getlefteyeX(), getlefteyeY(), geteyewidth(), geteyeheight(), 0, -180);
        }

        public void CloseRightEye(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
            g2d.drawArc(getrighteyeX(), getrighteyeY(), geteyewidth(), geteyeheight(), 0, -180);
        }

        public void lipSmile(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
            g2d.drawArc(getsmileX(), getsmileY(), getsmilewidth(), getsmileheight(), 0, -180);
        }

        public void lipFrown(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
            g2d.drawArc(getsmileX(), getsmileY() + 30, getsmilewidth(), getsmileheight(), 0, +180);
        }

        public void winkEye(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawArc(getrighteyeX() - 60, getlefteyeY(), 150, 250, 90, 45);
            g2d.drawArc(getrighteyeX() - 90, getlefteyeY() + 30, 150, 200, 60, 45);
        }

        public void narrowEye(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.fillOval(getlefteyeX() + 20, getlefteyeY(), geteyewidth() - 20, geteyeheight() + 30);
        }

        public void smallerSmile(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.fillArc(getsmileX() + 30, getsmileY() + 15, getsmilewidth() / 2, getsmileheight(), 0, -180);

        }

        //EXPRESSIONS
        public void DrawSmile(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            rightEye(g);
            leftEye(g);
            lipSmile(g);
        }

        public void DrawFrown(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            rightEye(g);
            leftEye(g);
            lipFrown(g);
        }

        public void DrawAngry(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(15));
            leftEyeAngry(g);
            rightEyeAngry(g);
            lipFrown(g);
        }

        public void DrawWink(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(15));
            winkEye(g);
            narrowEye(g);
            smallerSmile(g);
        }

        public void Glasses(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawOval(getlefteyeX() - 20, getlefteyeY() - 20, geteyewidth() + 40, geteyeheight() + 40);
            g2d.drawOval(getrighteyeX() - 20, getrighteyeY() - 20, geteyewidth() + 40, geteyeheight() + 40);
            g2d.drawArc(getlefteyeX() + 80, getlefteyeY() + 20, 50, 20, 0, 180);
        }

        public void glassesDark(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.fillOval(getlefteyeX() - 20, getlefteyeY() - 20, geteyewidth() + 40, geteyeheight() + 40);
            g2d.fillOval(getrighteyeX() - 20, getrighteyeY() - 20, geteyewidth() + 40, geteyeheight() + 40);
            g2d.drawArc(getlefteyeX() + 70, getlefteyeY() + 20, 70, 20, 0, 180);
        }

        public void DrawShock(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(15));
            g2d.drawLine(getlefteyeX() - 10, getlefteyeY(), getlefteyeX() + 40, getrighteyeY() - 20);
            g2d.drawLine(170 + getlefteyeX() + 40, getlefteyeY(), 170 + getlefteyeX() - 10, getrighteyeY() - 20);
            g2d.fillOval(getrighteyeX() - 20, getrighteyeY(), geteyewidth() + 20, geteyeheight() + 20);
            g2d.fillOval(getlefteyeX(), getlefteyeY(), geteyewidth() + 20, geteyeheight() + 20);
            g2d.fillOval(getsmileX() + 40, getsmileY() + 25, geteyewidth() + 20, geteyeheight() + 30);
        }




}
```

Comment: Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I've edited my post

Comment: You missed the point about "minimal". If you can't isolate and demonstrate the problem in minimal code I doubt you will get much help.